# Modify default value of socket buffer sizes in windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets

In the socket programming, SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF will have the default value as the 8192 bytes when the size of RAM is greater than 19MB.

Now, I want to change the socket buffer sizes for my sockets.I know that one way is by setsockopt. But, I want to apply changes to the system default, and be able to use the modified value of the socket buffers for all the sockets I create in the system. Please let me know where do I make the configuration changes in windows platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here there is a description of how it works:
http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-winsock-buffer.html

And the solution should be:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet \Services \Afd \Parameters]
DefaultReceiveWindow = 16384
DefaultSendWindow = 16384
```

Comment: Although I added this parameters, the socket is not picking this values.It is using its default values only. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @sreepurna Did you restart the service after modifying the register key? You may be able to use netsh (but I don't know the excat command) or you can reboot the system.